# cmd prompt in win10 opens/closes immediately when executed

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

I have executed `sfc /scannow` using PowerShell, tried the Rkill code, items are being corrected using these fixes, but not the problem with the cmd prompt 'open then close' issue. It doesn't matter whether I trigger cmd using the Windows + R key, calling from Start, etc. I am the administrator, so I use 'run as administrator'. And the cmd.exe is on the system and I tried executing from inside File Explorer.

The registry entry i found looks like this:
[registry entry for 'command processor'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJZeL.png)

I have read all the prior questions around this topic. There was one entry in a prior question that proposed reloading Windows as a repair. I really dread that option. Are there any other things that are worth trying?

Comment: Try the following:   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Does `cmd /d` stay open?